# Evernote Mac Open PDF From a Url

Tags: pdf, url, evernote

Is there a way to add a pdf file to Evernote on Mac directly from a url.  Either using the web clipper or the full application.

Say there is a url at www.fakeurl.com/file.pdf (this is not a real url) I either want to be able to open the url directly in evernote or navigate to the url and use the web clipper to add the pdf to evernote.

Currently, I have to download the pdf and then add the file to Evernote, I would just like to do it in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trying to figure this out, all you have to do is drag the url from your browser to the Evernote application icon and it will download the pdf directly into Evernote.